# Get values of checkbox from multiple rows of checkboxes in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple rows of modules with `manage access right` and you can choose which `right` you want for a user.

Now I want to get the `checked` box from these checkboxes `name="config{{$field->id}}"`

Currently I have this working code.

HTML

```
 @if(count($manage_access_list))
                    @foreach($manage_access_list as $field)
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                {{$field->access_desc}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                            <select class="access-select mdb-select accessSelect{{$field->id}}" data-id = "{{$field->id}}" name="accessSelect{{$field->id}}" id="accessSelect{{$field->id}}" style="width: 170px!important;">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Access Right</option>
                                    <option value="ALL">All Access</option>
                                    <option value="NO">No Access</option>
                                    <option value="CONFIG">Custom Access</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2 access-right-{{$field->id}}" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add{{$field->id}}" name="config{{$field->id}}" id="add{{$field->id}}">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="add{{$field->id}}">Add</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 access-right-{{$field->id}}" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input edit{{$field->id}}" name="config{{$field->id}}" id="edit{{$field->id}}">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="edit{{$field->id}}">Edit</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 access-right-{{$field->id}}" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input remove{{$field->id}}" name="config{{$field->id}}" id="remove{{$field->id}}">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="remove{{$field->id}}">Remove</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
```

Output:

[image]

and here's how I wanna get the values but don't know where to start

`newUserSubmit` is a button that is used when submitting the `form`

```
$("#newUserSubmit").click(function () {
....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you also putting your id's inside your class names? Simply give all your check boxes a common class name, select all of those in JS and loop over them to perform a task on each or do as you wish with all the values.

```js
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('common');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  console.log(checkboxes[i].name + ' is ' + checkboxes[i].checked)
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="1" class="common">
<label for="1">First</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="2" class="common">
<label for="1">Second</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="3" class="common" checked>
<label for="1">Third</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="4" class="common">
<label for="1">Fourth</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you know what to select, in the example below I've selected all checkboxes in the document. Ideally you'd want to narrow it down either by calling find on a parent, or building a query with a parent selector before it.

Something like `$('.access-rights input[type="checkboxes"]')` works the same(ish) as `$(".access-rights").find('input[type="checkboxes"]')` That way you only get the checkboxes you want.

Ideally you don't put your id's in classes etc...  You put them in something like you have on all the checkboxes. That way you can just select them with `$('input[type="checkbox"][data-id="id here}");` The only thing you need to do then is figure out how to transfer the serverside generated ID into the client side javascript.

Please see the example below.

```js
$('#clickme').on('click', (e) => {
  $('.access-rights input[type="checkbox"]').each((index, elem) => {
    console.log('checkbox with name: ', elem.name, ' is ', elem.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 access-right-{{$field->id}} access-rights" >
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add{{$field->id}}" name="config{{$field->id}}" id="add{{$field->id}}" data-id = "{{$field->id}}">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="add{{$field->id}}">Add</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 access-right-{{$field->id}} access-rights" >
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input edit{{$field->id}}" name="config{{$field->id}}" id="edit{{$field->id}}" data-id = "{{$field->id}}">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="edit{{$field->id}}">Edit</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 access-right-{{$field->id}} access-rights" >
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input remove{{$field->id}}" name="config{{$field->id}}" id="remove{{$field->id}}" data-id = "{{$field->id}}">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="remove{{$field->id}}">Remove</label>
 </div>
</div>
<button id="clickme">Click me</button>
```